# Android layout_gravity problem?

Tags: android, android-layout, gravity

Following is my xml
  I want to set `button1` to left centrally vertical and `button2` to right centrally vertical but for me `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"` is not working what is the wrong?
I know that i can achieve this by applying by using padding or margin but I won't know that why it is not working. **How should I make it work?**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HorizontalScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                />
        <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button2"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"/> 
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
  </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here your problem is as you are using `HorizontalScrollView` , as a result `FrameLayout` is not being able to make its width to `fill_parent`.If you remove the `HorizontalScrollView` you will get the desired result I think.

Comment: True, As an items filling at run time the button is automatically going to right side.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you replace **HorizontalScrollView** with **LinearLayout**, then you will see the desired effect.